# After installing Ubuntu, can't boot into Windows using the UEFI boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I recently have installed Ubuntu previously 18.04 but also 20.04) on dual boot with Windows 10. When the installation was completed, I could boot in Windows 10 and Ubuntu using Grub but, when I tried to boot in Windows using the UEFI boot menu (f9 on HP), I had an error message telling me the bootloader wasn't found. I didn't find anything like that on Google, but problems I found was on HP for some (maybe a coincidence). So do you know how the installation of Ubuntu could corrupt the Windows bootloader (in UEFI boot menu). I can't recreate the error because I've uninstalled Ubuntu (for obvious reasons), and backup the bcdedit list.

Comment: Whats wrong with just booting Windows the way that works?  If you want you can run Boot Repair from a USB and convert the whole thing to UEFI.  I think its not worth it.

Comment: @walttheboss the problem is that i can’t boot into Windows using the UEFI boot menu, so if Grub has a problem, I can’t boot neither in Ubuntu or Windows

Comment: @K7AAY I tried with Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

Comment: Can you boot either OS now?  Can you boot Windows in non-UEFI mode?  Does the Grub boot-loader screen show up with choices? What does that look like?  When UEFI was introduced there was such chaos.  From the standpoint of us who want Dual-Boot it became a challenge as every manufacturer handled things differently. Much depends on the Bios.  There are three things that all work together or against each other and you have to get them right for Dual-Boot to work well. Fast-Boot, Secure-Boot and Legacy Rom.  I don't understand it all but have fought hours long battles till all of a sudden it works

Comment: @walttheboss as is said, I backuped the bcdedit, so now, everything is working as before. There isn’t dual boot at all now. I asked how did the problem happen, not to solve it, but to now how it happened, and how to avoid it for other people. So I repeat the question: How, with two differents installations of Ubuntu, the installation medium deleted my Windows entry?

Comment: OK.  Sorry for misunderstanding. I do not have an answer.